# Is the tool to measure wire gauge called a wire gauge gauge?

Tags: tools

The thickness of a cable is its gauge.
Therefore, my question consists of inquiring whether the tool to measure it is called a gauge gauge?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a [standard round gauge tool](https://www.homedepot.com/c/ab/how-to-read-a-wire-gauge-chart/9ba683603be9fa5395fab9015a6d2c99), [wire gauge measuring tool](https://www.google.com/search?q=standard+round+gauge+tool&oq=standard+round+gauge+tool), or metal round gauge tool.